# SQL Using Like, One Variable, Multiple Columns

Tags: sql

```
--where 'email@aol.com' in(o.SuOrderEmailAddress, o.SuBusEmailAddress, o.SuReturnEmail, O.SuPartsEmail) and es.ictid = 7
```

I want to search one variable (email address) in the multiple columns. This is what I have now, and it works.

I think I need to use Like, because I want to use wildcards. For instance, being able to use *@aol.com would be very helpful. Right now I have to enter an exact email address.

```
--Where s.suname like 'rizt%'and es.ictid = 7
```

It was simple enough in this above example, but once I rearrange the syntax to do multiple columns Im lost as to where I can use LIKE so that I can use Wildcards.

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: This might sound stupid because I am new at this, but how can you tell?

Answer (score 0):

You could just look at the end of the email address.  Most databases support the `right()` function:

```
where '@aol.com' in (right(o.SuOrderEmailAddress, 8),
                     right(o.SuBusEmailAddress, 8),
                     right(o.SuReturnEmail, 8),
                     right(o.SuPartsEmail, 8) 
                    ) and
       es.ictid = 7
```

(Even databases that don't have `right()` have an equivalent function, in general.)

Some databases support regular expressions, which is another option.  Or, in your case, string concatenation would even work.

EDIT:

If you have a variable, you can do:

```
where @var in (right(o.SuOrderEmailAddress, len(@var)),
               right(o.SuBusEmailAddress, len(@var)),
               right(o.SuReturnEmail, len(@var)),
               right(o.SuPartsEmail, len(@var)) 
              ) and
       es.ictid = 7
```

Comment: This would work alright in a lot of cases, but in instances where a more common email is used, like aol, Im going to get far too many results.

Basically I need to identify a specific employee assigned to work with various email contacts, so in cases where it wasnt a specific business name this would be problematic

Comment: Actually, the more I look at this the more feasible it is. Im assuming the 8 indicates how many characters it is looking at? Is there any way to change that without needing to put a specific number? Like could I remove the character limit completely, or is there a way to put some sort of variable in there? * or % or something?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the real answer is to use Full Text Indexing (if you are using MS SQL - otherwise seeing if there is an equivalent for whatever server you are using).  However, here is an ugly hack that should work:

```
WHERE ISNULL(o.SuOrderEmailAddress, '') + '|' 
      + ISNULL(o.SuBusEmailAddress, '') + '|' 
      + ISNULL(o.SuReturnEmail, '') + '|' 
      + ISNULL(O.SuPartsEmail, '') LIKE @pattern
```

This simply concatenates all of the relevant fields into a pipe-delimited list before checking that concatenated string for the @pattern.

Comment: Im pretty new to this, so what do '|'  indicate?. I tried using this and it runs without error, but I come up with no results

Comment: You would have to check for null on each.

Comment: @Tyler I edited my answer with a small explanation.  The "pipe" character isn't anything special, it's just a character that is unlikely to be in the fields you are checking - it's just a delimiter.  Let's say you were looking for "comed" in the list of email addresses - you'd want to match "joe@comed.com" or "comed@somelistserv.org", but not "joe@aol.com" followed by "ed@aol.com".

Comment: If it's still not working after you add the ISNULL checks, then verify that `@pattern` is set correctly.  For searching "@aol.com", `@pattern` should be '%@aol.com'.  And make sure that you are using parameterized queries!

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea. Usually, @search would be a parameter to a stored proc. Look at the WHERE clause first.

```
    declare @search varchar(50) = '@aol.com'

    set @search = '%' + @search + '%'

    select case when o.SuOrderEmailAddress like @search then o.SuOrderEmailAddress
                when o.SuBusEmailAddress like @search then o.SuBusEmailAddress 
                when o.SuReturnEmail like @search then o.SuReturnEmail
                when o.SuPartsEmail like @search end as matchedEmail    
    from MyTable as o
    where (o.SuOrderEmailAddress like @search
           or o.SuBusEmailAddress like @search
           or o.SuReturnEmail like @search
           or o.SuPartsEmail like @search) and ...
```

You could control the adding of '%'s on the front end. This seems to me to be written clearly for the reader and gives you back the email address that was the match.